# an error when trying to download torch in stable diffusion, what do i need to do?

Tags: python, windows, pip, torch

```
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: D:\AIART\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AIART\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 360, in <module>
    prepare_environment()
  File "D:\AIART\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 269, in prepare_environment
    run(f'"{python}" -m {torch_command}', "Installing torch and torchvision", "Couldn't install torch", live=True)
  File "D:\AIART\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 89, in run
    raise RuntimeError(f"""{errdesc or 'Error running command'}.
RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.
Command: "D:\AIART\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install torch==1.13.1+cu117 torchvision==0.14.1+cu117 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Error code: 2
```

i tried to redownload the correct version of the python but it seems not to be working

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Python
Install Python 3.10.6|
Delete VENV file in stable-diffusion-webui
Run .bat file again